# How to register a device token with Firebase for push notifications in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, firebase, notifications, token

I need help registering a list of tokens with Firebase to receive notifications in Spring Boot. Here's my current logic flow:

Controller.class

```
public class Controller {
  @PostMapping(value = "/pushNotification")
  public ServiceResponse pushNotification(@RequestBody SignalDto signalDto) throws FirebaseMessagingException {
    log.info("Send Email: {}", signalDto);
    BatchResponse response = appPushService.sendAppPushMessageTest(signalDto);
    return ServiceResponse.success(response, Constants.SUCCESSFUL_MSG, Constants.SUCCESSFUL_CODE);
  }
}
```

AppPushService.interface

```
public interface AppPushService{
  BatchResponse sendAppPushMessageTest(SignalDto signalDto) throws FirebaseMessagingException;
}
```

AppPushServiceImpl.class

```
public class AppPushServiceImpl implements AppPushService {
  private final FirebaseCloudMessageService firebaseCloudMessageService;
  private final RegistrationTokenRepository registrationTokenRepository;

 public BatchResponse sendAppPushMessageTest(SignalDto signalDto) throws FirebaseMessagingException {
      BatchResponse batchResponse = null;

        try {

            List<String> userNames = new ArrayList<>();
            userNames.add("username.test");
            final List<String> registrationTokens = registrationTokenRepository.findByUsername(userNames);
            if(registrationTokens.size() > 0) {
                BatchResponse messageResponse = firebaseCloudMessageService.sendSignalNotificationTest(signalDto, registrationTokens);
               batchResponse = messageResponse;
                log.info("sendFirebaseNotification successfully {}", messageResponse);
            }

        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
            log.error("sendFirebaseNotification {}", e.getMessage());
        }
       return batchResponse;
    }
}
```

FirebaseCloudMessageService.class

```
public class FirebaseCloudMessageService {

  public BatchResponse sendSignalNotificationTest(SignalDto signalDto, List<String> registeredTokens)
          throws IllegalArgumentException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException, FirebaseMessagingException {


    Notification notification = Notification
            .builder()
            .setTitle(signalDto.getTitle())
            .setBody(signalDto.getBody())
            .setImage("https://www.test.com/uploads/demo/logo-header.png")
            .build();

    //Set date
    signalDto.getData().put("date", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    return sendToFireBaseTest(notification, signalDto.getData(), registeredTokens);
  }
  
   private BatchResponse sendToFireBaseTest(Notification notification, Map<String,String> data, List<String> registeredTokens)
          throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, FirebaseMessagingException {

    FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance();
  
    MulticastMessage message = MulticastMessage.builder()
            .putAllData(data)
            .addAllTokens(registeredTokens)
            .setNotification(notification)
            .setWebpushConfig(WebpushConfig.builder().setFcmOptions(WebpushFcmOptions.withLink("https://test.com/")).build())
            .setAndroidConfig(AndroidConfig.builder().setTtl(3000).build())
            .build();

    final BatchResponse response = firebaseMessaging.sendMulticastAsync(message).get();
    if (response.getFailureCount() > 0) {
      List<SendResponse> responses = response.getResponses();
      List<String> failedTokens = new ArrayList<>();
      for (int i = 0; i < responses.size(); i++) {
        if (!responses.get(i).isSuccessful()) {
          failedTokens.add(registeredTokens.get(i));
        }
      }

      log.error("List of tokens that caused failures: " + failedTokens);
    }
    return response;
  }
}
```

SignalDto.class

```
public class SignalDto implements Serializable {
  @Serial
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -743000069269581435L;

  private String type;
  private String title;
  private String body;
  private Map<String,String> data;
}
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
  <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
  <version>9.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Resource

```
notificationapp.json
```

Application-local.properties

```
firebase.admin-sdk=notificationapp.json
```

What step am I missing? Please provide a solution.

What step am I missing? Please provide a solution.